# How to solve "QML module not found (QtMultimedia)"

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I'm importing `QtMultimedia 5.4` to use a `Camera` but its raising this error `QML module not found (QtMultimedia)`.

I've tried to echo the `$QML_IMPORT_PATH` as well as the `$QML2_IMPORT_PATH` which gave nothing.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: Hi, I'm running Qt Creator 5.11.2.